# how to set programmatically center_horizontal for a button in relativelayout?

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout, center

I want to make programmatically a background and a button after clicking on an another button. for this as I understand I need Relativelayout. But how should I actually set  center_horizontal for the button in that relativelayout? I found CENTER_IN_PARENT but what I need is center_horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

-Method   `addRule`  of the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class can be used.
-and by using following snippet of code you can solve your problem.

```
layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
Your Button.setLayoutParams(Yourlayoutparams);
```

-THanks! and you can still ask more if you cant get it.!